# Download PDF nodejs + expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I am making a GET request to download a PDF file through the browser, but I do not get a response. I do not know where I'm going wrong. Follow my code

**My Controller**

```
download: function(req, res) {

        var nomeContrato = req.params.contrato;
        var cpfAluno = req.params.cpf

        db.query("select descricao from tparametro where valor = 'PATH'", function (err, rows) {

            if (err) {
                var message = err.message;
                console.log('Erro ' + message);

                return res.status(500).send(message);

            }else {

                var caminhoDiretorio = rows[0].descricao;
                var caminhoComSubdiretorio = caminhoDiretorio + path.sep + cpfAluno;
                var caminhoCompleto = caminhoComSubdiretorio + path.sep + nomeContrato;

                fs.readFile(caminhoCompleto, function(err, arquivo) {  
                    if (err) throw err;
                    //console.log('Arquivo:' + arquivo);
                    var data = [];
                    data.push(arquivo);
                    data = Buffer.concat(data);
                    //console.log('Arquivo:' + data);
                    res.writeHead(200, {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
                        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=some_file.pdf',
                        'Content-Length': data.length
                      });
                      res.write(data);
                      res.end(data);
                });

            }

        });
    }
```

**The browser receives the response**

[image]

**Response HEADER**

[image]

Comment: can you add your request header ?

Comment: Can you show what is returned in the 'headers' tab?

Comment: @bendataclear 
Enter my response header

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to use 'res.sendFile(), something like :

```
   var filePath = "./dir/example.pdf"
   return res.sendFile(filePath);
```

Comment: I'll try NiallJG

Comment: The result is the same as the image I typed, the browser response is ok. But did not download the pdf

Comment: try hard coding a full file path ( from the host's root directory )  to a pdf  and sending a test file

Comment: This is the complete path with my pdf C: \ development \ GitPersonal \ 2019 \ contracts \ 09919718688 \ contract-80201910352.pdf

Comment: Set filepath to equal this string and see what you get

Comment: Okay, I'll do it

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't just do:

```
var caminhoDiretorio = rows[0].descricao;
var caminhoComSubdiretorio = caminhoDiretorio + path.sep + cpfAluno;
var caminhoCompleto = caminhoComSubdiretorio + path.sep + nomeContrato;

res.download(caminhoCompleto);
```

Comment: The result is the same as the image I typed, the browser response is ok. But did not download the pdf

Comment: @EdeGerSil Make sure not to use the `res.writeHead` if you use `res.sendFile` or `res.download`.

Comment: did not work, the response is of success equal to the image that I inserted. But do not download